# One button that cycles through URL's that can work with HTML/Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a button that I would like to cycle through multiple URL's when clicked.

Example: Person comes to website -> Clicks button.

Button checks to see which URL is next in a sequence, and sends user to the next url in a sequence.

Thus creating a button that can serve multiple URL's, one for each click.

---

Something like this:

```
?php

$link[1] = "http://www.site1.com";

$link[2] = "http://www.site2.com";

$link[3] = "http://www.site3.com";

if(!isset($HTTP_cookie_VARS['link'])){ $n=count($link);

$rand=rand(1,$n); setcookie("link",$rand,time()+3600);

header('location:'.$link[$rand]); }else{ $go=$link[$_COOKIE['link']]; header('location:'.$go); }

?>
```

---

Though, something that would work in HTML?

Comment: do you mean the same user comes back and sends them to a new link, or every time anyone in the world clicks the button in cycles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this per person, then cookies is the way to go. Make an array of the links, and store the pointer number in the cookie. Check if cookie, if no cookie, make cookie and send to first link, else increment number in cookie, click that link. Don't forget to also check if its the last link stored in the cookie so you can set it can go back to the first one.

I won't code it for you, but here is the structure for your code:

```
make an array of links

if (cookie exists) {
    if (lastNum) {
        set cookie to 0
        send to link 0
    }
    else {
        set cookie to num+1
        sent to link num+1
    }
}
else {
    set cookie to 0
    send to link 0
}
```